# How to make portable visual studio 2012? (using external drive and scripts)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, batch-file, cmd, registry

So I have a problem that I need visual studio on three different computers, and I can have only a temporary vs12 installation on each of those.

What I did:

1. Connected my external drive, and set it's volume letter to `G:`
2. Installed as much as I can on that drive, rest of it installed on `%SystemDrive%`
3. Copied all files from `%SystemDrive%` to my `G:` drive
4. Made a `cmd` script to create Junction directories in `%SystemDrive%`

**CMD script:**

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"
mklink /J "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" "G:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
mklink /J "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" "G:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
```

1. Made a `cmd` script to delete them after work is done

**CMD script:**

```
rd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"
rd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
rd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
rd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
rd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
```

**Conclusion:**

1. How can I find all registries for visual studio?
2. Where I can find information on how to create registries with `.bat` or `cmd` scripts?
3. And where can I find information how to successfully delete them?
4. **Want to know, if it's even possible to achieve what I want?**

Comment: There are tools that take a snapshot of your registry before and after an install. You can use the REG command to add/modify keys or simpler: use regedit with a file as argument to read a wholebunch of keys.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using a virtual machine?

Comment: @WilliamBettridge-Radford actually good point, I could use [Portable-virtual box](http://www.vbox.me/) and then I could run it on every machine without altering registries and directories. I will post instructions after some testing on both ways. Thanks for opening my eyes to obvious solution :)

Comment: You can probably do this with Spoon (formerly Xenocode), but it costs money. One free alternative I know of is Cameyo, but there are probably more. I do know that they not always work, but they may work (Spoon allowed me to run every single version of IE from IE6 to IE11 on Windows 7, and I'm aghast at that being possible ([see!](http://i.imgur.com/bW1p99T.png))).

Comment: @CamiloMartin thanks! I was looking for something like this, never thought it is possible.

Comment: I just tested it and, damn. You *can* virtualize VS 2010! (I'll stick with it until VS 2013). ([pic 1](http://i.imgur.com/Toio4HY.jpg), [pic 2](http://i.imgur.com/GhTXjaE.png)).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try WIN PE technics - guess VS goes to deep inside the system and needs deep integration.

With Install Rite (http://www.pcwelt.de/downloads/Install-Rite-2-5-1332314.html) you could get an overview of what happens really during installing VS to see what you need to imitate.

Registry entries you could easily export and import between machines and the same way round, while install rite will help you with this.

**This magic driver** (http://write-code.blogspot.de/2010/08/file-redirection-using-driver-fsredir.html#.Up46WKMwd9A) works well under normal windows too, and i used it in cases to redirect apps that normally can't get redirected :) You can use it at installtion time already D)

While here is an app equivalent and already portable, maybe an Option? http://portableapps.com/node/32713

Another idea would be to take a small VMware machine with you, if mounting local devices then is functional for your work.